# Efficient aggregation of high dimensional arrays

Tags: matlab

I have a 3 dimensional (or higher) array that I want to aggregate by another vector. The specific application is to take daily observations of spatial data and average them to get monthly values. So, I have an array with dimensions `<Lat, Lon, Day>` and I want to create an array with dimensions `<Lat, Lon, Month>`.

Here is a mock example of what I want. Currently, I can get the correct output using a loop, but in practice, my data is very large, so I was hoping for a more efficient solution than the second loop:

```
% Make the mock data
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
X = zeros(2, 3, 9);
for j = 1:9
  X(:, :, j) = A;
  A = A + 1;
end

% Aggregate the X values in groups of 3 -- This is the part I would like help on
T = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3];
X_agg = zeros(2, 3, 3);
for i = 1:3
  X_agg(:,:,i) = mean(X(:,:,T==i),3);
end
```

In 2 dimensions, I would use `accumarray`, but that does not accept higher dimension inputs.

Comment: `for` has become significantly more efficient. I wouldn't consider it a bottleneck anymore. Having that said - maybe you can replace it with `parfor` to use your additional cores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before getting to your answer let's first rewrite your code in a more general way:

```
ag = 3; % or agg_size

X_agg = zeros(size(X)./[1 1 ag]);

for i = 1:ag
  X_agg(:,:,i) = mean(X(:,:,(i-1)*ag+1:i*ag), 3);
end
```

To avoid using the `for` loop one idea is to [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) your X matrix to something that you can use the `mean` function directly on.

```
splited_X = reshape(X(:), [size(X_agg), ag]);
```

So now `splited_X(:,:,:,i)` is the i-th part
that contains all the matrices that should be aggregated which is `X(:,:,(i-1)*ag+1:i*ag))` (like above)

Now you just need to find the mean in the 3rd dimension of `splited_X`:

```
temp = mean(splited_X, 3);
```

However this results in a 4D matrix (where its 3rd dimension size is 1). You can again turn it into 3D matrix using `reshape` function:

```
X_agg = reshape(temp, size(X_agg))
```

I have not tried it to see how much more efficient it is, but it should do better for large matrices since it doesn't use `for` loops.

Comment: Thanks. Simple simulation shows this to be about twice as fast as my method. I also need to reshape later in my code, so I can combine some steps.